# SVGtransform:rotate() not working in ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, css-transitions

Iam using svg in in a block level element> I try to rotate that block using transformrotate(180deg).This is working fine in firefox and chrome and IE Edge.When i open IE9 it is not working.How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does not support `transform: rotate(180deg)`, you must add `-ms` prefix to make element transform.

Code Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/s8hdhurc/

```
<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <!-- This is important as -ms-rotate does not work in quirks mode -->
            <style>
                .rotate {
                    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg); /* IE 9 */
                    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari */
                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="rotate">
                <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```